# Replacement for starting threads from a for loop

Tags: python, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
def start_threads(self):
    thread_pool = []
    for obj in self._objs_list:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self._do_task, args=(obj,))
        thread_pool.append(thread)
        thread.start()
    for thread in thread_pool:
        thread.join()

    self._do_final_task()
```

`_do_task` is basically a method which process some I/O operations and I want to to execute it in parallel for each `obj` in `self._objs_list`

I want `self._do_final_task()` to be executed only once all the threads finished their job.

My code works, however it is very ugly and immature (it seems). Is there a more elegant way of doing so?

Comment: The more code that is included, the better the review we can give. We need to see the `_do_task` method, and it would be better still if we saw all the code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw sadly, I cannot post my code here. I understand that in this case it really matters, however - is there a more elegant way of writing into a thread pool and executing the same logic as appears above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for many situations, modern Python does not require so much
hoop-jumping for multithreading or multiprocessing situations -- no need to
worry about appending, starting, and joining. A schematic illustration is shown
below. See the
[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool)
to decide which of the many flavors of map or imap to use for your situation.
In this example, return values from `self._do_task` will arrive as `result` in the for-loop.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def start_threads(self):
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        for result in pool.map(self._do_task, self._objs_list):
            ...
    self._do_final_task()
```

Comment: Thanks!
In my case I don't need the results, any way to get rid of that?

Comment: @eaRobust Then just call `pool.map()` directly (no loop) and ignore the list it returns.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate, another way to do modern concurrency in Python is using the `Executor` construct. Here's the schematic for your particular use case:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def start_threads(self):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as exe:
        for obj in self._objs_list:
            exe.submit(self._do_task, obj)
    self._do_final_task()
```